# Is it possible to open multiple instances of programs in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, single-instance

Some programs only allows single running instance, 
Is there any way to generally break this in Windows for all programs?
Am currently working with Windows Movie Maker and need to open multiple instances

Comment: Which program are you talking about ?

Comment: Windows Movie Maker

Comment: you may be able to run an instance each under two different user acccounts. to try, create a second user, and set its password. On your desktop, run Movie Maker. Then find its launcher, and Shift + RClick it -> "Run as Differant User". Enter the username and password for your new user, and see if it runs. no way to tell it will work for sure with this app until you try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because those programs typically check for running instances of themselves. It is not a windows feature.

Comment: Second this.  I've had multiple instances of programs open at once, no problems.  Programs may enforce a single instance for various reasons--I've even run into one that enforces no more than 6 instances.  (Poor man's batch processing since their own batch processing is bugged.)

Comment: Right, I wrote an application where users opened multiple instances and messed up files because of multiple instances where they couldn't remember which one had the most current data, and their misuse of my application was somehow my fault. I now have the application check to see if it is already running when launched, and it brings up the existing application window and terminates the newly launched application.